# WPF Usercontrol Property Intitialization

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am playing around with WPF Usercontrols and have the following question: why does the behaviour of property initialization/assignment change after a property is made to a `DependencyProperty`?

Let me briefly illustrate:

Consider this code for a `UserControl` class:

```
public partial class myUserControl : UserControl
{
    private string _blabla;
    public myUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _blabla = "init";
    }

    //public static DependencyProperty BlaBlaProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    //    "BlaBla", typeof(string), typeof(UserControlToolTip));

    public string BlaBla
    {
        get { return _blabla; }
        set { _blabla = value; }
    }
}
```

And this is how the `UserControl` is initialized in the XAML file:

```
<loc:myUserControl BlaBla="ddd" x:Name="myUsrCtrlName" />
```

The problem I have is that the line *set { _blabla = value; }* is called ONLY when the *DependencyProperty* declaration is commented out (as per this example). However when the *DependencyProperty* line becomes part of the program the *set { _blabla = value; }* line is no longer called by the system.

Can some please explain this strange behavior to me?

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLR wrapper (getter and setter) of a dependency property should only be used to call the `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods of the dependency property.

e.g.

```
public string BlaBla
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(BlaBlaProperty) }
    set { SetValue(BlaBlaPropert, value); }
}
```

and Nothing more...
The reason for this is that the  WPF binding engine calls `GetValue` and `SetValue` ***directly*** (e.g. without calling the CLR wrapper) when binding is done from the XAML.

So the reason you don't see them called is because they really aren't and that is precisely the reason why you shouldn't add any logic to the CLR Get and Set methods.

**Edit**
Based on OPs comment - here is an example of creating a callback method when the `DependencyProperty` changes:

```
public static DependencyProperty BlaBlaProperty = 
       DependencyProperty.Register("BlaBla", typeof(string), Typeof(UserControlToolTip), 
       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnBlachshmaPropertyChanged));


private static void OnBlachshmaPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
        UserControlToolTip owner = d as UserControlToolTip;

        if (owner != null)
        {
            // Place logic here
        }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Blachshma, thanks very much for this, but in this case how do you *intercept* **GetValue/SetValue** calls for a Dependance Property and where do you ad your own logic for changes in values? I currently intercept calls for new values for a UserControl at the get/set location as per above in order to take some action inside the control depending on the value.

Comment: You can create a callback method when the dependency property is changed. Example added to my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @Blachshma - this was great help and advice! I got the UserControl framework to work now!